# comparing two Character array and get the character value and form a string

Tags: java, arrays

I have two character arrays here with predefined values. I want to get the change from the two arrays.
Here is the predefined values of the two arrays:

```
Character[][] arr1 = new Character[row][column];
arr1[1][0] = 'K';
arr1[1][1] = 'E';
arr1[1][2] = 'P';
arr1[1][3] = 'T';

Character[][] arr2 = new Character[row][column];
arr2[0][1] = 'H';
arr2[1][0] = 'K';
arr2[1][1] = 'E';
arr2[1][2] = 'P';
arr2[1][3] = 'T';
arr2[2][1] = 'L';
arr2[3][1] = 'P';
```

And with this code I am getting the change which is "HLP" which is correct

```
final Character[][] arr3 = new Character[row][column];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        if (arr1[i][j] != arr2[i][j]) {
            s = arr2[i][j];
            arr3[i][j] = s;
        }
    }
}

//generate the word from the compared arrays
for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        if (arr3[r][c] != null) {
            l = arr3[r][c];
            k = Character.toString(l);
            out = builder.append(k).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to include the space in between the `H` and `L` and include it in my string out. Can anybody give me any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What about including the space when you append the string?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but it sounds like [Sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment).

Comment: @Dukeling I am want to include the space between H and L..either I will add add to include it in the string or something else..

Answer (score 0):

You could append a space when the value in the array is null. In the for loop where you generate the word you add an else statement to the existing if and specify that it should append a space.

Comment: I tried appending space, but I still did not get the word HELP. the output looks like this 'PHLP'....

Comment: I'm confused. You said you wanted to add space between H and L. I interpreted it as your output should look like "H    LP" (four spaces because there are four characters in between). Now you're saying you want to get the word "HELP". Please clarify this.

Comment: ah ok, now I got you. Then I'd recommend declaring a boolean variable which saves whether the last character from the array was null (outside the for loop). You can then add an else if statement to the existing if (no else statement anymore) where you would check if the character is null AND the last character is not null (using the former introduced variable). This will only add one space between the characters. You will also have to set the boolean variable to true inside this else if and set it to false in the existing if.